# Basic Java type casting issue

Tags: java

I've an interface called DataHandler with the following declaration among others:

```
public List<Object> getIt();
```

while the ProjectSet class implements this interface.

This class handles Project objects and the implementation of the **getIt()** method for the ProjectSet class should return a list of Projects
like:

```
List<Project>
```

How to do this in Java?

Regards,
Gerard

Comment: Have you tried anything? would be helpful to have at least a bit of your attempt to solve it.

Comment: Yes, but unfortunately I got a lot of errors, and need a better understanding of generics!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take advantage of [Generics in Java](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java) by declaring the method in your interface as:

```
public interface DataHandler<T> { 
    public List<T> getIt();
}
```

This means that the `DataHandler` interface is tied to a specific, unknown type `T`. The `getIt()` method returns a `List` of that class `T`. In other words, it could be seen as *`DataHandler` will handle objects of class `T`*.

And then provide your implementation, specifying that `ProjectSet` will be a `DataHandler` handling `Project` objects:

```
public class ProjectSet implements DataHandler<Project> { 

     public List<Project> getIt() { }
}
```

You might find [this lesson of the Java Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/index.html) useful.

Comment: Thanks for your clear answer and pointing me towards the very basics of Generics!

Answer (score 1):

```
public List<T> getIt();
```

in your interface and

Like this

```
public interface MyInterface<T> {

  public List<T> getIt();

}
```

then implement it with

```
implements MyInterface<Project>
```

Comment: I need to go back to the basics!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that in java this way.

My solution would be to have the data handler be generic

```
public interface DataHandler<T> {
     public List<T> getIt();
}
```

then you can do

```
public ProjectSet implements DataHandler<Project> {
     public List<Project> getIt() { ... }
}
```

Comment: Rather straightforward, but I need a better understanding of all this! Sorry, for having bothered you with this basic issue!

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 options:

#### Change the interface to be Generic:

```
interface DataHandler<T> {

    List<T> getIt();

}

class ProjectSet implements DataHandle<Project> {

    List<Project> getIt() {
         ...
    }
 }
```

This is hard because you need to change the interface, and refactorize all classes that implements `DataHandler`. This some thimes is not a option.

#### Cast a List

The type information of the list is gone in runtime, for this, all List type are equals in runtime, and equal to Object, so you can do this:

```
class ProjectSet implements DataHandle {

    List<Object> getIt() {
         ...

         return (List) projectList;
    }
 }
```

This is Ugly, but works!, you can add a `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` to skip the warnings.

#### Create a List of Objects

```
class ProjectSet implements DataHandle {

    List<Object> getIt() {

         List<Object> retObject = ... ;

         for (Project p : getProjects()) {
                retObject.add(p);
         }

         return retObject;
    }
 }
```

This is only ugly!.